# C++ allocating array non contiguously

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management

Let's consider this C++ code as a rough example.

```
int *A = new int [5];
int *B = new int [5];
int *C = new int [5];
delete []A;
delete []C;
int *D = new int [10];
```

Obviously any machine can handle this case without any problems with buffer overflow or memory leak. However let's imagine that the lengths are multiplied by one million or even a bigger number. As far as I know addresses (at least virtual addresses) of all array elements are consecutive. So whenever I create an array I can be sure that they are contiguous chunks in virtual memory and I can perform pointer arithmetic to access n-th element if I have pointer to the first one. My question is illustrated in the following image( registers representing end of array are ignored for the sake of simplicity).
[image: heap array allocation]

After allocating A, B, C in the heap we free A and C and get two free memory chunks of length 5 (marked with green dots). What happens when I want to allocate an array of length 10? I think that there are 3 possible cases.

- I will get bad_alloc exception for not having contiguous 10 length memory chunk.
- The program will automatically reallocate array B to the beginning of the heap and join together the rest of the unused memory.
- The array D will be split into 2 parts and stored not contiguously causing not constant access time for n-th element of the array (if there are much more than 2 splits it starts to resemble a linked list rather than an array).

  Which one of these is most possible answer or is there another possible case I didn't take into account?

Comment: This is very OS dependent.

Comment: @JamesAdkison yes, let's assume that we have only 15 registers of heap memory. Otherwise the question would be meaningless.

Comment: It also ignores the fact that programs use *virtual* memory as opposed to *physical hardware memory*. It is more a theoretical question. The theoretical answer would be to expect `new` or `malloc` to return `NULL` on subsequent request for greater than available memory.

Comment: this would work if you were using a java or c# vm. i don't think malloc can defragment your memory for you.

Comment: Your title is extremely generic. Please make it identify the question.

Comment: The first bullet point.

Comment: @Ben No, this has nothing to do with the OS.

Comment: @n.m. so your saying memory allocation and shifting like this would be the same on an Arduino as it is in windows? I feel like RTOS like RTEMS would certinaly behave differently to OSX when encountering fragmented memory (ie. RTEMS does nothing OSX probably does something) ...

Comment: @Ben Yes in fact, absolutely the same in Windows, Linux, whatever RTOS you have, this is handled by the language runtime, not the OS.

Comment: @Ben And if there is no OS or the code _is_ the OS?

Comment: @Ben in a hypothetical situation where `free` or `delete` actually return memory to the OS, the fourth bullet point can be in effect, namely, "the OS creates a new contiguous 10 length memory chunk out of two 5 length chunks by reassigning their virtual addresses accordingly". I know of no C++ implementation that does that.

Comment: @Ben well, scratch that; this is actually done by glibc for large memory chunks, so bullet point four is a real possibility.

Comment: @n.m. So the OS must also update the value of pointer to B which is stored in the stack, am I right ?

Comment: No, see my answer for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I will get bad_alloc exception for not having contiguous 10 length memory chunk.

This can happen.

> The program will automatically reallocate array B to the beginning of the heap and join together the rest of the unused memory.

This cannot happen. Moving an object to a different address is not possible in C++ because it would invalidate existing pointers.

> The array D will be split into 2 parts and stored not contiguously causing not constant access time for n-th element of the array (if there are much more than 2 splits it starts to resemble a linked list rather than an array).

This also cannot happen. In C++ array elements are stored contiguously, so that pointer arithmetic is possible.

But there are in fact more possibilities. To understand them, we must account for the fact that the memory can be virtual. This, among other things, means that available address space may be larger than the amount of physically present memory. A chunk of physical memory can be assigned any address from the available address space.

As an example, consider a machine with 8GB (2^33 bytes) of memory running a 64-bit os on a 64-bit CPU. Addresses allocated to the program do not gave all be less that 8GB; it can receive a megabyte chunk of memory at address 0x00000000ffff0000 and another megabyte chunk at address 0x0000ffffffff0000. The total amount of memory allocated to the program cannot be more than 2^33 bytes, but each chunk can be located anywhere in the 2^64 space. (In reality this is a bit more complicated but similar enough to what I describe).

In your picture, you have 15 little squares that represent chunks of memory. Let's say it's physical memory. Virtual memory is 15,000 little squares, of which you can use *any* 15 at any given time.

So, considering this fact, the following scenarios are also possible.

- A chunk of virtual address space is given to the program that is not backed by real physical memory. When and if the program attempts to access this space, the OS will try to allocate physical memory and map it to the corresponding address so that the program can continue. If this attempt fails, the program may be killed by the OS. The newly-free memory is now available to other programs that may want it.
- The two short chunks of memory are mapped to new virtual addresses such that they form one long contiguous chunk in the virtual memory space. Remember that typically there are many more virtual memory addresses than there is physical memory, and it is normally easy to find an unassigned range. Typically this scenario is only realized when the memory chunks in question are large.

Answer (score 7):

The problem that you are asking about is called heap-fragmentation, and it's a real, hard problem.

> I will get bad_alloc exception for not having contiguous 10 length memory chunk.

This is the theory. But such a situation is really only possible within a 32-bit process; the 64-bit address space is *vast*.

That is, with a 64-bit process, it is more likely that heap fragmentation stops your `new` implementation from reusing some memory, which leads to an out-of-memory condition since it needs to ask the kernel for new memory for the entire `D` array instead of half of it. Also, such an OOM-condition will more likely cause your process to get shot by the OOM-killer sometime when you try to access a location in `D`, rather than `new` throwing an exception, because the kernel won't realize that it has overcommitted its memory before it's too late. For more information, google "memory overcommitment".

> The program will automatically reallocate array B to the beginning of the heap and join together the rest of the unused memory.

No, it can't. You are in C++, and your runtime does not know where you have possibly stored pointers to `B`, so it would either run the danger of missing a pointer that needs to be modified, or run the danger of modifying something that's not a pointer to `B` but happens to have the same bit pattern.

> The array D will be split into 2 parts and stored not contiguously causing not constant access time for n-th element of the array (if there are much more than 2 splits it starts to resemble a linked list rather than an array).

This is also not possible because C++ guarantees contiguous storage of arrays (to allow array accesses to be implemented via pointer arithmetic).

Comment: Memory overcommitment only happens on some OSes, and only when you do not sensibly limit memory available to programs via `ulimit` or some such tool.

Comment: @n.m. True, but at least it affects all linux installations, which means that the vast majority of computing devices does memory overcommitment. I don't know about windows, though; don't they do memory overcommitment as well?

Comment: Embedded devices normally have overcommitment turned off (or at least they should!)